# How do I run dropbox?

Tags: xubuntu, dropbox, appmenu

I have installed dropbox on ubuntu 16.04.

I have had it run before.

Now I have restarted and it is not running.

How do I start it manually, as I don't want it to automatically start on startup?

Comment: What happens when you click on the Dropbox icon in the Dash?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open it by searching for DropBox where you look for applications and then clicking the icon for it.

Alternatively you should be able to start it through Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) by running:

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Comment: it does not show up in a application search.